# Swift how to sort an array of custom objects in a given order with property

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, swift3

I have an array of restaurantsIds in a specific order. I make a network call to get Restaurants for each one of these ids. I am returned with all the Restaurants in the order that they are returned. Restaurants is a custom class and one of the properties is restaurantId. I want to sort the returned Restaurants in the order of the IDs. How would I do that? I think I am supposed to use the sorted function. How would I go upon doing this? There can be duplicate restaurants so I can't use a dictionary to do it. If is is a duplicate restaurant that is returned then it doesn't really matter which instance of that restaurants comes first.

```
var restaurantIds = [947575, 858914, 255964]
var returnedRestaurant:[Restaurant]!
returnedRestaurant.sorted { (rest1, rest2) -> Bool in
        //How would I go about matching rest1 and rest2 to the list of restaurantIds above?
        rest1.productID......
    }
```

Comment: That would sort it numerically, I want to sort it by the custom order that is in the restaurantIds array.

Comment: You're making a "network call" but how? Are you requesting them one by one, are you requesting them all at once and getting a list back, do they get returned with the id as part of the data? We really need more information or we're just guessing at a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly you wish to sort your array by the order the IDs occur in `restaurantIds`.

`Array` provides the method `index(of:)` which given an element returns the index of its first occurrence in the array. For example `restaurantIds.index(of:858914)` would return `1`.

You can use the result of `index(of:)` as your sorting key. I.e. In your sorting function the value you need to compare for `rest1` would be `restaurantIds.index(of: rest1.productID)`.

HTH

**Addendum**

@vacawama raises and issue with is both correct in principle but may be wrong in practice... Using `restaurantIds.index(of: rest1.productID)` a *lot* is not good for performance and for longer lists of restaurant IDs you may need to optimise by avoiding the repeated `index(of:)` calls. However for short lists any performance change (it could be a win or lose) is probably insignificant and optimisation just complicates the code.

TL;DR: YMMV, KISS, beware premature optimisation, your call.

Comment: I think this is what OP is looking for. Rest of the answers wont work.

Comment: For anybody now reading this, @adev was correct at the time. Now vacawama's solution also works and is a different take on the same idea. Take your pick.

Comment: Probably putting in an ordered set may help with index issue assuming ids are unique.

Answer (score 2):

Create a dictionary that maps the restaurantID to the order of that ID.  You can then use that to sort your array:

```
var restaurantIds = [947575, 858914, 255964]

// Create a dictionary that maps the order of the restaurantID
var order = [Int: Int]()
for (idx, rid) in restaurantIds.enumerated() {
    order[rid] = idx
}

var returnedRestaurant:[Restaurant]!

returnedRestaurant.sort { (rest1, rest2) -> Bool in

    // look up the order for the restaurant id.  If the id is missing, use
    // Int.max to put that restaurant at the end of the array

    let order1 = order[rest1.id] ?? Int.max
    let order2 = order[rest2.id] ?? Int.max

    return order1 < order2
}
```

If you have more than just a few restaurant IDs, this is likely more efficient than repeatedly using `index(of:)` to figure out the mapping.  The larger your restaurant array, the more times `index(of:)` is called (because `sort` is `O(n log n)`) so the number of calls to `index(of:)` grows rapidly as the size of the restaurant array increases.  `index(of:)` is an `O(n)` operation based upon the size of the id array.  The larger your id array, the slower `index(of:)` becomes.

Comment: "This is more efficient..."? In the example `restaurantIDs` is short, it could of course be longer but given its a list of IDs is an iOS app to look up in a database we can probably guess its not that large. A dict requires dynamic allocation and hash calculations on insertion and lookup. Array's `index(of:)` probably needs to offset calculations (might just iterate) and will average n/2 comparisons. Either approach *could* be faster, data dependent, but is it really important? Are you sure this isn't premature optimisation? (I admit, I considered a dict, we all get tempted to not KISS ;-))

Comment: @CRD, there are advantages both ways.  If OP really only has 3 ids, then a dictionary is overkill. The list of restaurant IDs is known ahead of time, so the dictionary can be created at that time instead of waiting for the restaurants to be read.  In a sort, the same lookup will happen repeatedly, so `n/2` adds up.  I don't think this is *premature optimization*.  It's thinking about an algorithm that scales nicely.  With 6-digit restaurant ids, there are probably more than 3.

Comment: Edit is good, but you should probably still have a "probably" in there ;-)

Comment: I know this will eventually be more efficient than `index(of:)`.  The only remaining question in my mind is where the break even point is.  If the dictionary can be created ahead of time, then the break even point is even lower.

Comment: We're dancing here, I say "probably", you say "eventually" ;-) You got my original point, however poorly expressed, nice talking to you.

Comment: @vacawama, got a valid point. That is why I upvoted this too that time. Instead of dictionary an ordered set should work too right?

Comment: @adev, Swift doesn't have a native ordered set. You'd still be using `index(of:)` with NSOrderedSet.  I'm not sure how that compares to an array or a dictionary lookup.  The documentation does say that testing inclusion is faster for an ordered set than an NSArray, but this question needs the index of the item being searched.

Comment: True, I forgot swift didn't have ordered set. I was thinking of `NSOrderedSet`. But the lookup on set should be faster compared to Array by definition of set. But yes, dictionary lookup and set lookup should be similar in performance. That is why I put that comment as a question.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to iterate through your `restaurantIds` array using `flatMap` and return the first element from your `returnedRestaurant` array whose id matches the id at the current index in `restaurantIds`. This function returns a new sorted array and doesn't mutate the `returnedRestaurant` array in place.

```
let sortedRestaurants = restaurantIds.flatMap{ id in
    returnedRestaurant.filter{$0.restaurantId == id }.first
}
```

Comment: If you use a flatmap function on restaurantIds it would flatten the array of restaurantIds but we don't want to flatten the array, we just want to sort the returnedRestaurant in the order based on the restaurantIds array using the id within each Restaurant. I haven't tried this yet but if you think it will work I will give it a try.

Comment: As long as you don't have duplicate restaurantIds this works.  If you do have duplicateIds, then this drops all but the first restaurant found.

Comment: @vacawama you are right, I assumed ids to be unique. But this solution can easily be modified to work with repeating ids as well.